# How do I open the Windows scheduled task's properties window

Tags: windows-7, windows-task-scheduler

Windows stores some scheduled tasks in C:\Windows\Tasks. Some applications which schedule tasks somehow open the individual task's properties, such as in this screenshot:
[image: Task Properties]

How can I open such window myself? I do not see the task in the standard Task Scheduler, probably because these tasks are the legacy 32-bit scheduler jobs.

Comment: You did open that window in screenshot. Then what window do you want to open?

Comment: @Biswa: I want to be able to open any job from that folder like this. The window in question is invoked by an application, but it is obviously a system built-in. Besides, the screenshot was stolen from elsewhere.